# Integral limit $\lim _{t\to 0}\frac 1 t \int_0^1 (f(x+t)-f(x))x \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

Let $f:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx=0$. Compute the following limit:
$$\lim _{t\to 0} \frac 1 t \int_0^1 (f(x+t)-f(x))x \, dx$$
I thought about Lagrange's Theorem but we don't know if $f$ is differentiable so it can't be used in this case.

Comment: $t\in(-x,1-x), \forall x\in[0,1]$ doesn't make much sens ... since $t$ must be fixed in the integral (before taking the limit) and $x$ moves in $[0,1]$ : let $t$ fixed, then $x=1$ implies $t\in (-1,0)$, but for $x=0$, you must have $t\in (0,1)$... So, the integral is well defined only for $t=0$ ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the problem of the definition of $\int_0^1\left(f\left(x+t\right)-f\left(x\right)\right)xdx$ (since $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$,the latter integral only has sense for $t=0$), see my comment under the original question.

---

In the following I will suppose that is not an issue (It is sufficient for example to assume that $f$ is defined and continuous over $[0,1+\varepsilon)$ with $\varepsilon>0$)

Act as if $f$ was $\mathcal{C}^1$ at first (the inversion limit/integral is then alright from domination convergence theorem) to have an idea of what the limit can be : 
$$ \lim _{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\int_0^1\left(f\left(x+t\right)-f\left(x\right)\right)xdx = \int_0^1 f'(x)xdx= [f(u)u]_0^1 -\underbrace{\int_0^1 f(x)dx}_{=0}=f(1). $$

---

In the general case, 
let 
$$ F(t):= \int_0^1 f\left(x+t\right) xdx$$
then the limit you seek is 
$$\lim _{t\to 0}\frac{F(t)-F(0)}{t} = F'(0)$$

Now 
\begin{align*}
 F(t) & = \int_0^1 f\left(x+t\right) xdx \\
& = \int_t^{1+t}f(y)(y-t) dy \tag{$y=x+t$}\\
& = \int_t^{1+t}f(y)y dy -t\int_t^{1+t}f(y) dt
\end{align*}
So (since if $G(t):=\int_0^t h(y) d y$ with $h$ continuous, $G$ is differentiable and $G'(t)=h(t)$) :
$$F'(t) = f(1+t)(1+t)-f(t)t-t(f(1+t)-f(t)) -\int_t^{1+t}f(y) dy$$
and 
$$ F'(0)=f(1)- \int_0^{1}f(y) dy=f(1).$$
So the limit remains true in the general case.

Comment: If $y\in (1,1+t]$ how does $f(y)$ exist? $$F(t)  = \int_0^1 f\left(x+t\right) xdx 
 = \int_t^{1+t}f(y)(y-t) dy \tag{$u=x+t$}$$

Comment: @ChristianF I know (from the start, but I thought  there was a problem in the definition in the original question  (see my edit))